# Security mode="None

Tags: wcf, security

I have some collegues who have build a WCF Service.  Their security settings are the following:

```
security mode="None"
   transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""
   message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"   
       establishSecurityContext="true" 
security
```

Does it makes sense to specify the security mode="None" and then specify transport/message security underneath?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679999/wcf-with-no-security

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just basically **NO SECURITY** at all - that doesn't make any sense at all - except for maybe development time :-)

If you have `<security mode="None">` then anything you specify below is not taken into account - you could leave that out just as well.

Answer (score 1):

It does no harm, the mode="None" value means none of the individual settings for either message or transport will be used.